# Disable-output-escaping="yes-no" not working &amp; outputted twice in Sharepoint URL

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010, escaping

I have a custom content type with a custom field of type TEXT. 
This field contain a URL that starts with protocol DynamicsNav: so sharepoint does not permit to manage this field as a standard "safe" hyperlink field.
This field is rendered through a XSL Template and is represented by a fixed text.

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[@Name='DSErpHyperlink']" mode="Text_body">
<xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@DSErpHyperlink" disable-output-escaping="yes" /> 
    </xsl:attribute>
    Open
</a>
```

**Field DSErpHyperlink Contains**

```
dynamicsnav://servername:7041/ServiceName/CRONUS Italia S.p.A./runpage?page=30&bookmark=224;GwAAAACJBDEwMDE=&mode=Create
```

But is rendered with double amp; so doesn't works.

```
<a href="dynamicsnav://servername:7041/ServiceName/CRONUS Italia S.p.A./runpage?page=30&amp;amp;bookmark=224;GwAAAACJBDEwMDE=**&amp;amp;**mode=Create"> Open</a>
```

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED !
This works

> ```
>     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;a href="</xsl:text>
>     <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@DSErpHyperlink" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
>     <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">" &gt;Open&lt;/a&gt;</xsl:text>
> ```

Instead of this that doesn't work

```
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@DSErpHyperlink" disable-output-escaping="yes" /> 
        </xsl:attribute>
        Open
    </a>
```

Because disable-output-escaping is not working for attributes I think

Answer (score 3):

**Here is a simple way to do this, that doesn't require using DOE**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="x">
  <xsl:variable name="thisNode" select="."/>
     <a href="{$thisNode/@DSErpHyperlink}">SomeLinkText</a>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
 <x DSErpHyperlink=
  "dynamicsnav://servername:7041/ServiceName/CRONUS Italia S.p.A./runpage?page=30&amp;bookmark=224;GwAAAACJBDEwMDE=&amp;mode=Create "
/>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced** :

```
<a href="dynamicsnav://servername:7041/ServiceName/CRONUS Italia S.p.A./runpage?page=30&amp;bookmark=224;GwAAAACJBDEwMDE=&amp;mode=Create ">SomeLinkText</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The specification states that disable-output-escaping is ignored when writing an attribute node. As Dimitre says, you don't need it.